# ROR - Requesting JSON from Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a form which uploads a file via ajax (using remotipart gem) which is working fine. I would like the response from the server as JSON and trigger a javascript function on the browser. How can I achieve that? Can I change the setting in the form tag?

View:

```
<%= form_tag import_companies_path, remote: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<%end%>
```

Contoller:

```
def import
    respond_to do |format|
      options = { col_sep: ',', converters: :numeric, headers: true }
      array = []
      CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, options) do |row|
        array.push(row.to_hash)
      end
      logger.debug "Parsed CSV companies: #{array.inspect}"
      format.html { redirect_to companies_path }
      format.json{
        render json: { items: JSON.pretty_generate(array)}
      }
      format.js { render js:  JSON.pretty_generate(array) }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using several techniques.

One of them is to use your form as is, just adding a javascript function which will receive json data:

```
<script>
  function receiverFunction(data) {
    console.log(data.name)
  }
</script>
<%= form_tag ... %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
format.js {
   @data = { name: 'Dora' }
}
```

In your `import.js.erb`:

```
receiverFunction(<%= @data.to_json.html_safe %>)
```

This will transfer `@data` in `json` format to `receiverFunction` on your page.

Comment: Awesome this worked! Whats the other option? I would like to handle ajax success/error...

Comment: @Emon other options are: (1) send ajax using jquery on form submit; (2) reply with `json` format instead of `js`, but this involves listening on form events (`ajax:complete`), and actually it's not proper use of `remote: true` either. I would bet on (1) or what is given in my answer. The answer is more "Railsy" then the option (1).

Comment: one more way is to remove even `receiverFunction` from the form view and define it in `js` view. But in my opinion it's too far fetching.